# Is If/else AND order by within a join possible?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-filter-view

I have N tables each in its own sheet combined into one master table but I need to sort out empty rows and sort the output alphabetically.

[Working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gVggzSolf2xHqfYU25jTO2_AnRd19GxSZnyiHQSeQlw/edit?usp=sharing)

Is that even possible to combine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This too long formula, but can still give the hoped result

```
={Nema!A2:F2; array_constrain(sort({Staff!A3:A9,Staff!B3:F9,row(Staff!A3:A9)-row(Staff!A1);
sort(FILTER (
{ 
 left(Nema!A1:A9,0) & Nema!A1,Nema!B1:F9,row(Nema!A1:A9)-row(Nema!A1);
 left(Flash!A1:A9,0) & Flash!A1,Flash!B1:F9,row(Flash!A1:A9)-row(Flash!A1);
 left(Muhammad!A1:A9,0) & Muhammad!A1,Muhammad!B1:F9,row(Muhammad!A1:A9)-row(Muhammad!A1);
 left(Allan!A1:A9,0) & Allan!A1,Allan!B1:F9,row(Allan!A1:A9)-row(Allan!A1);
 left(Joy!A1:A9,0) & Joy!A1,Joy!B1:F9,row(Joy!A1:A9)-row(Joy!A1)

},
{  
   row(Nema!A1:A9)-row(Nema!A1);
   row(Flash!A1:A9)-row(Flash!A1);
   row(Muhammad!A1:A9)-row(Muhammad!A1);
   row(Allan!A1:A9)-row(Allan!A1);
   row(Joy!A1:A9)-row(Joy!A1)
}>1,
   {
     Nema!A1:A9;
     Flash!A1:A9;
     Muhammad!A1:A9;
     Allan!A1:A9;
     Joy!A1:A9
   }<>"",
   {
     Nema!B1:B9 & Nema!C1:C9 & Nema!D1:D9 & Nema!E1:E9 & Nema!F1:F9;
     Flash!B1:B9 & Flash!C1:C9 & Flash!D1:D9 & Flash!E1:E9 & Flash!F1:F9;
     Muhammad!B1:B9 & Muhammad!C1:C9 & Muhammad!D1:D9 & Muhammad!E1:E9 & Muhammad!F1:F9;
     Allan!B1:B9 & Allan!C1:C9 & Allan!D1:D9 & Allan!E1:E9 & Allan!F1:F9;
     Joy!B1:B9 & Joy!C1:C9 & Joy!D1:D9 & Joy!E1:E9 & Joy!F1:F9
   }<>""),1,true)}   ,7,1),1000,6)}
```

Comment: This is perfect! When you say the formula is too long, do you think there is a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't know, but my formula is too long, I think

Comment: OK. Thank you for your effort. It works just perfect.